# Prevent multiple transfer operations with Azure Storage Data Movement Library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I just started to use [Azure Storage Data Movement Library (DML)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) having code similar to [public  DML sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs#L297). Use case is to (incrementally) sync a local directory to blob storage several times while some files in the directory are updated from time to time.

```
UploadDirectoryOptions options = new UploadDirectoryOptions
{
    SearchPattern = "*.*",
    Recursive = false,
    BlobType = BlobType.BlockBlob
};

// Register for transfer event.
DirectoryTransferContext context = new DirectoryTransferContext();

//only copy newer files - similar to AzCopy /XO /XN switches
//https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/12
context.ShouldOverwriteCallback = (source, destination) =>
{
    var sourceFile = new FileInfo((string)source);
    var destBlob = destination as CloudBlob;
    return sourceFile.LastWriteTimeUtc > destBlob.Properties.LastModified;
};

// Start the upload
var transferStatus = await TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(sourceDirPath, destDir, options, context);
```

Currently a transfer operation is triggered by an application event. Having experimented with a couple of events in short time, this raised an exception as shown below. Since TransferManager is a static class, how to address this requirement in my application and prevent such exceptions?

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: A transfer operation with the same source and destination already exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added more than 1 transfer task with same source/destination to the TransferManager (such as, run above code several times in your application) . If so, you will meet the issue as the  DMlib don't allow to run more than 1 transfer task with same source/destination at same time.

Comment: The question outlines that more than one transfer task was added to the TransferManager. Do you have any suggestions how to design something around TransferManager that ensures subsequent transfer tasks with same source/destination wait for completion of any actual transfer task? Is any of the 4 test projects (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/tree/master/test) addressing issues like this? If so, I could explore its source code.

Comment: You should wait() for the 1st task finish, then add the 2nd task with same source/destination. Please note, the 2nd task should use a new checkpoint (new transferContext), and can't use the checkpoint (transferContext) of the finished task  with same source/destination.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some pointers. Would you mind to add some code to illustrate further what you have proposed in short since I did not find any public code samples going beyond the rather simple DML sample code linked in the question?

Comment: I think I will just catch these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is not well optimized. I feel that you had the same problem as I had. Let me shortly explain. you are running asynchronous DirectoryUpload, of course in this case  "multiple transfer operations" will be.

In most cases This exception occurs if file is skipped. thats why you are getting an error as "A transfer operation with the same source and destination already exists." In this case, progress will skip the image, you must catch those as below. see the full sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs)

```
 DirectoryTransferContext context = new DirectoryTransferContext();
            context.FileTransferred += FileTransferredCallback;
            context.FileFailed +=FileFailedCallback;
            context.FileSkipped += FileSkippedCallback;

            context.SetAttributesCallback = (destination) =>
            {
                CloudBlob destBlob = destination as CloudBlob;
                destBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";
            };

            context.ShouldTransferCallback = (source, destination) =>
            {
                // Can add more logic here to evaluate whether really need to transfer the target.
                return true;
            };

            // Start the upload
            var trasferStatus = await TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(sourceDirPath, destDir, options, context);

private static void FileTransferredCallback(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transfer Succeeds. {0} -> {1}.", e.Source, e.Destination);
    }

    private static void FileFailedCallback(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transfer fails. {0} -> {1}. Error message:{2}", e.Source, e.Destination, e.Exception.Message);
    }

    private static void FileSkippedCallback(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transfer skips. {0} -> {1}.", e.Source, e.Destination);
    }
```

what was missing in the sample is how to handle overwriting existing images if they arent the same.

I am not sure if this was available in the version 0.3 but I only figured out also after installing version 0.4.1 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement package. Code below will compare source and destination and decide if should overwrite or not.

```
   context.ShouldOverwriteCallback = (source, destination) =>
                    {
                      if(TransferContext.Equals(source, destination)==true)
                            return false;
                      else
                            return true;                        

                    };
```

Comment: This issue was about multiple transfer operation with same source and destination running at same time. This is not supported by DML at the moment. I updated my code sample to address your answer/comment. I needed a solution for incremental operations as well - similar to existing switches in AzCopy.

Comment: Is it not causing Performance decrease as you read each file in the blob before you overwrite?

Comment: The callback works on metadata that DML is querying anyway. Since this operation is about skipping upload of larger files (MB/GB), it is perfectly worth the price. Optimization of this callback is in duty of DML developers.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried I just tested looks quite good. I adjusted my code based on that also. thanks :)

Comment: what does the `TransferContext.Equals` method compare in `source` and `destination` ?  Is it only the name or other attributes like `Last Modified` or `Blob Type` as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to run the upload for 10 times. Please modify as your requirement.
Please note, you need to wait for the before task finish, then add a new transfer task with same source and destination with new transfer context.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Create Transfer Context
            DirectoryTransferContext context = new DirectoryTransferContext();

            //if dest blob exist just overwrite it 
            context.ShouldOverwriteCallback = TransferContext.ForceOverwrite;

            // Start the upload and wait for it to finish
            Task<TransferStatus> task = TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(sourceDirPath, destDir, options, context);
            task.Wait();

            //Add some code to check the task.Result, following code only print the result
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", task.Result.NumberOfFilesTransferred, task.Result.NumberOfFilesFailed, task.Result.NumberOfFilesSkipped, task.Result.BytesTransferred));
        }
```

Comment: this code sample does not convey anything useful with regard to prevent multiple transfer operations with same source/dist in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: Please note, in the code, it will wait() for a task finish, then add a task with same source and destination. So with this code, the issue won't happen. Not sure what other kinds of sample you would like to have?

Comment: Anyway, probably I have to improve my question

Comment: @WeiWei-Microsoft How do you not ForceOverwrite but overwrite only if datemodified is newer? How can I sync between source and destination?